# How do I use OfflineImap / Isync with a server with self signed certs (reading emails in Mutt)?

Tags: linux, email, imap, mutt, offlineimap

I am trying to download my emails from mmy imap server (to use with Mutt), but hitting a wall here. I keep getting cert errors. I searched the web and found some solutions however those solutions seems to apply for cases where there is a known root ca.

How can I get either of these apps to work with a server that has self signed certificates?

Other apps(clawsmail, thunderbird etc) have no problem with self signed stuff. The issue is that I would like my imap mails to get synced locally.

If these do not seem to work, do you recommend any other solution that can work with Mutt?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For OfflineIMAP at least, I believe you need to get OpenSSL working first. There are some instructions in the [FAQ](http://docs.offlineimap.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#does-offlineimap-verify-ssl-certificates). [This](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OfflineIMAP#SSL_fingerprint_does_not_match) might also be relevant.

Sorry for the lack of detail. It's been a while since I configured OfflineIMAP and I rather rusty. Don't remember having to do anything special actually to support odd cert issues.